# Align the form / delete button with the other buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table, and at the end of the table are some options.
View, Edit and Delete. I need the Delete button to be a form so I can POST the delete.

My button/form doesn't sit on the same line though, and I am not sure why, I've used the form-inline class, and tried just setting it display inline-block but nothing is working for me. Using bootstrap 3.2.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojuLe

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="/foo/1">View</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/foo/1/edit">Edit</a>
            <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="/foo/1">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Something else</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/foo/2/edit">Edit</a>
            <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="/foo/2">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers by default set `form` elements to display as blocks. To change this, you simply need to  set your `form` to display `inline`. As your `form` element already has a class of `.form-inline`, we can style that particular class to appear this way:

```css
form.form-inline {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FLlgo).